# An interal error occured during "TestNG listening job" port value out of range -1

Tags: java, selenium

Hi while running TESTNG I am getting this error "An interal error occured during "TestNG listening job" port value out of range -1". How can I fix this

Comment: Same problem after installing update for eclipse  at 1/2/2017 (installation of the last JRE  won't help)